# Resetting the position of the ball and the paddle when the player loses a life

Tags: vb.net

I am designing a Breakout style game where you knock down bricks to earn points and complete the game. The game consists of a paddle, ball, and some bricks. I have implemented the changes in the ball direction when it bounces off the sides of the screen. So, when the ball touches the left and right sides, it will bounce back the other direction and when the ball touches the top side, it will bounce back the opposite direction. However, when the ball hits the bottom side, it should decrease the number of paddles left by 1 and, both the ball and paddle should appear in its original position (i.e. on the paddle). This is what I have coded for this:

```
    'check bottom of screen 
    If PictureBox_ball.Top >= 403 Then
        Timer_Main.Enabled = False
        lbl_PaddlesLeft.Text = lbl_PaddlesLeft.Text - 1
        PictureBox_ball.Location = New Point(321, 365)
        PictureBox_paddle.Location = New Point(288, 383)
        Timer_Main.Enabled = True
    End If
```

when I run this code, it refuses to change the location of the paddle. It just stays where it is. Would this be affected by what I have coded for the movement of the paddle? This is what I have coded:

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    If e.X > 0 And e.X < Me.Width - PictureBox_paddle.Width Then
        PictureBox_paddle.Location = New Point(e.X, PictureBox_paddle.Top)
    End If
End Sub
```

If the number of paddles is less than 0 (total paddles = 3) and the ball reaches the bottom of the screen then the game should display a message box saying "You Lost!". This is what I have coded for this:

```
    'check number of paddles left and bottom of screen 
    If lbl_PaddlesLeft.Text < 0 And PictureBox_ball.Top >= 403 Then
        Timer_Main.Enabled = False
        MsgBox("You Lost!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel)
    End If
```

However, when I run this code, the message box does not display when the paddles is less than 0. All it does is the ball starts from the original position even though the paddles left is a negative number. How do I fix this?
**Note: The first and third snippet of the code is in the Timer_Main_Tick event**

Comment: Your MouseMove event sets the paddle to the position of the mouse, even if you reset the paddle position, it will go back to where the mouse is as soon as you move. For the second question, it's hard to know... are you sure your code is being executed? I strong suggest you look at setting option strict on, you'll see a lot of errors appearing but it'll definitely make your code cleaner and less chances of having weird errors in the future.

Comment: If you are at -1 paddles and the ball goes to the bottom, do you get the message?  You are only checking if the number is paddles is less than 0 not equal to zero.  That would depend on how you are displaying and handling the available tries though.